# Desktop LCD monitor flickering from dark to faint display of the screen

Tags: display, lcd

I have this 19" LCD Viewsonic monitor from 2005.  Yesterday, it starts flickering from dark(as if it is turned off) to very faint display of the screen.  After I shut down my computer while the monitor is still plugged in, I still observe that behaviour.  My display and power connections are secured.  I don't believe I have any power issues at my place.  Does that mean that the monitor is dead and it's time to get a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sounds like a hardware issue to me, but to be sure, you should try plugging it into another computer and seeing if the issue persists.

There is a stupid little controller board (lcd inverter) that tends to fail, and cause this sort of a problem...I've seen it a lot with laptops, but I've never seen someone replace one on a monitor...The price point on the board is high enough that it's not usually worth it, and it's totally not worth it if you have to pay someone else to install it.

Comment: The monitor still flickers while just powered on and not connected to my PC, I just tossed it away, it served me well for 4 years.